# using distinct keyword in SQl query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, distinct-values

I want to retrieve a table which has repeated values in column1, column2 and column3. column 4 has different sets of data corresponding to value in column3. How should I query such a table?

Ex:

```
District  | City           | Place 
----------|----------------|-------------
bangalore | bangalorerural | indiranagar
bangalore | bangalorerural | jayanagar
```

I want to display bangalore, bangalorerural once with indiranagar and jayanagar in other rows.

Comment: Not sure it can be done into a table but you can get a similar structure by returning xml

Comment: Plese provide desired output. I understand that data provided in the question is table from which you'd like to get data and not the result. If it's the other way around, then provide an example table data. I can't really say whether you'd like to concatenate column3 or something else...

Comment: Please give an example of the output

Answer (score 3):

UNPIVOT is what you're after

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=UNPIVOTData

Comment: I understand that the question is vague, but... how can it be about UNPIVOT? What have you deduced is to be unpivoted here?

Comment: Bangalore need to be displayed once. i.e. an UNPIVOT. I'm only going with what I figure the asker is asking. I think they need to clarify by giving an example of the output now I've re-read